# How to start the Sharepoint app development

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, oauth

How to start the SharePoint App development ?

What is the SharePoint Hosted App Model ?

What is the open authorization 2.0 OAuth 2.0 ?

i am new to office 365 and develop apps for share point 2013,

can you provide one example in which case to use oauth 2.0 and sharepoint  Server to Server Security token service (STS)

. I have a sharepoint 2013 farm in one AD DS domain and has one intranet web site , and plan to develop sharepoint hosted add-ins which provide some functionality to intranet web site

. sharepoint hosted add-ins use windows authentication

.we have another Domain ( partner company domain) and we have plan to federate office 365 and will use this partner domain for office 365 services.

. and let users from partner company access on premise intranet site and  to use sharepoint hosted add-ins functionality , this custom app has access to all document libraries in intranet site.

Comment: msdn is your friend... Of course google too.. very general question. I would start with google, http://bfy.tw/7Eln

Answer (score 3):

First of all now SharePoint Apps are changing to SharePoint Add-ins. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161507.aspx#bk_newname).

And the answer to your question is to broad in context. We can just help you by providing the links.

SharePoint Add-ins are self-contained extensions of SharePoint websites that you create, and that run without custom code on the SharePoint server.

If you need to know about SharePoint Add-ins. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx).

There are two basic kinds of SharePoint Add-ins — **SharePoint-hosted and provider-hosted**. To make the best decision about the right kind to develop for your scenario, start by learning what both types of SharePoint Add-ins have in common.

**SharePoint Hosted App:**

SharePoint-hosted add-ins are one of the two major types of SharePoint Add-ins. For an overview of SharePoint Add-ins and the two different types, see SharePoint Add-ins. Here's a summary of SharePoint-hosted add-ins:

- They contain SharePoint lists, Web Parts, workflows, custom pages, and other components, all of which are installed on a subweb, called the add-in web, of the SharePoint website where the add-in is installed.
- The only code they have is JavaScript on custom SharePoint pages.

If you want to create your first SharePoint Hosted App then click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx)

Other best small demo for creating SharePoint Hosted App is shown in [How to create a basic SharePoint app](http://www.mstechbits.com/sharepoint-2013/how-to-create-a-basic-hello-world-sharepoint-app/).

**Open Authorization 2.0:**

> OAuth 2.0 is an open standard for authorization. OAuth is designed to
>   enable users to provide third parties with access to their resources
>   without sharing their credentials. Instead of credentials, an OAuth
>   access token is issued to the third party. The token grants access to
>   a specific resource, on a specific site, for a defined duration (for
>   example, 30 minutes), on behalf of a specific user. The Microsoft
>   server-to server protocol relies on OAuth to share information across
>   server platforms.

[OAuth 2.0 in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/oauth-20-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hi thanks for information you shared, also can you clear my confusion for sharepoint server to server token service is an authentication method or not for sharepoint hosted app? or OAuth 2.0 ?